# Можно ли в MS SQL за раз обновить разные XML-узлы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть команда `modify`, которая позволяет обновлять XML.

Собственно вопрос, а можно ли как-то выполнить обновление сразу нескольких узлов?

Например, есть 2 sql:column и я хотел бы за раз сделать 2 replace value of в 2-ух атрибутах конкретного узла.

Можно ли- это как-то сделать или никуда не уйти от последовательных обновлений?

Comment: Запись обновляется однократно. Если надо в одном поле одной записи выполнить сразу два изменения - их нужно выполнить одним выражением. Возможно, это будет сложный CASE.

Comment: @Akina, это я знаю. Другой момент, можно ли в modify написать какое-то сложное выражение. Вроде, в примерах нету, если я не упустил. Вот собственно, мне и интересно нет ли способов это провернуть.

Comment: Что мешает? `SET field = CASE WHEN condition1 THEN expression1 WHEN CONDITION 2 THEN expression2 WHEN ... END`. Ну или CASE внутри CASE, их вроде до 7 штук можно вкладывать. И соответственно в expression простые или вложенные Replace или иные функции корректировки значения.

Comment: @Akina, а мне не по условию обновлять нужно. Вот у меня есть 2 колонки в таблице и этими данными я хочу обновить за раз сразу 2 атрибута у конкретного узла по XPath.

Comment: Ну тогда вложенные функции, в чём проблема-то? `SET field = REPLACE(REPLACE(field, place1, value1), place2, value2)`, ну или что там для корректировки XML в заданной точке...

Comment: @Akina, ну вложенные Replace помогут на тривиальных случаях. Если у меня много одноименных узлов, а мне нужен узел по конкретному пути, то не прокатит=(

Comment: А что, корректировка узла по заданному пути - процедура? Ну тогда нарисуй свою функцию под это дело, и передавай ей все необходимые для мультиобновления параметры, пусть впахивает. Ну или нарисуй процедуру, которая выполнит два последовательных одиночных обновления.

Comment: @Akina, в теории можно. Я думал, что может быть какой-нибудь лайф хак есть, что бы сделать все за один XML.modify.

Comment: Возможно, CLR-функция будет лучшим решением.